# how to search a name that include apostrophe in SQL

Tags: php, sql, apostrophe

i want to search a title that include apostrophe in it.
i call the title from variable.

for example:

```
$mytitle = "Daddy's Home";
```

then i try to search it.

```
$apostrophe = $val;
$replacementsapostrophe = [
"'" => "''",
];
$newval = strtr($apostrophe, $replacementsapostrophe);

$query2 = $db->prepare ("SELECT category, id_master_post, master_post_name FROM `master_post` WHERE master_post_name = '$newval'");
$query2->execute();
$value2 = $query2->fetch();
```

Error given

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 's Home 2'' at line 1 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\piratefiles\list.php:31 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\piratefiles\list.php(31): PDOStatement->execute() #1
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\piratefiles\list.php on line 31

im already try `'%''%'` still not working.

Comment: did you try escaping the SQL syntax ?

Comment: How **specifically** are you trying to search it? Please include the supporting PHP code, not just your SQL statement itself; using prepared statements would solve this.

Comment: If the `$mytitle` has a single quote in it, your query will fail.  You should definitely be using prepared statements here.

Comment: *How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?*  = *How can I prevent ' breaking my querys in PHP?*

Answer (score 0):

You should use prepared statements to avoid sql injection but to answer your question . An example;

```
 try{
   $db=new PDO(DSN,USER,PASS);
 }catch(PDOException $e){
   echo "couldn't connect cos of $e";
}
$sqlQuery = "SELECT category, id_master_post, master_post_name FROM `master_post` WHERE master_post_name = ? "
$prepared= $db->prepare($sqlQuery);
$prepared->execute($myTitle);
$resultObject = $prepared->fetchObject() ;
```

Comment: Your suggestion to use prepared statements is good, but your answer is still using a PHP variable directly inserted into the string query.

Comment: "*Use prepared statements*" and "*just use the variable directly*" are mutually exclusive statements ;)

Comment: Yeah I just want to help him figure out what's wrong firstly. I'll update it to use prepared statements

Comment: sorry about it, im already add prepare but im not write full of my code. im edit it, and im try replaace `'` to `''`. i want to know is that save to using `strtr` in sql?

Comment: I just updated my answer to show you how it should work using prepared statements. You can try it